# How to find the solutions to $z^4 = -16$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, quartics

I'm having trouble finding the solutions to $z^4 = -16$

At first I did $\sqrt {z^4} = \sqrt {-16}$

Then I'd have $z^2 = 4i$ but this doesn't seem right or I just don't know what to do afterwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $z=re^{i\theta}$ so $$r^4e^{4i\theta}=16e^{i\pi}\to\\r=2\\4\theta=(2k+1)\pi\to\\\theta=\frac{2k+1}{4}\pi\qquad,\qquad k=0,1,2,3\to \\z=2e^{\dfrac{2k+1}{4}\pi}\qquad,\qquad k=0,1,2,3$$

Answer (score 2):

Instead of $z^2 = 4i,$ you actually need $z^2 = \pm4i.$

You have $$ 4i = 4(\cos90^\circ + i\sin90^\circ). $$ Therefore $$ \pm\sqrt{4i} = \pm 2(\cos45^\circ + i\sin45^\circ) = \pm2\left( \frac 1 {\sqrt2} + i\frac1 {\sqrt2} \right) = \pm (\sqrt 2 + i\sqrt2) $$ and then proceed similarly with $-4i.$

Comment: would your initial angles for $-4i$ be $270^\odot$

Answer (score 1):

It's $$z^4+16=0$$ or
$$z^4+8z^2+16-8z^2=0$$ or
$$(z^2-2\sqrt2z+4)(z^2+2\sqrt2z+4)=0,$$ which gives the answer:
$$\{\sqrt2+\sqrt2i,\sqrt2-\sqrt2i,-\sqrt2+\sqrt2i,-\sqrt2-\sqrt2i\}$$

Comment: How did you go from line 2 to line 3? @Michael Rozenberg

Answer (score 0):

You just calculate the (real)  $4$th root of $16$, and multiply by each of the (complex) $4$-th roots of $-1=\mathrm e^{i\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to find one.  You have
$$ - 16 = 16e^{i\pi} = (2e^{\pi/4})^4.$$
Can you find the others?  Four exist.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,z = r e^{i \varphi}\,$ in polar form, then solve $\,r^4 e^{4 i \varphi}= 2^4 e^{i \pi}\,$.

Comment: So from this method, do we arrive at $r^4=2^4e^{i(\pi - 4\varphi)}$ then take a fourth root and obtain $r=2e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4}-\varphi)}$

Comment: @HossienSahebjame What you get is $\,r^4 = 2^4\,$ and $\,e^{4i\varphi} = e^{i\pi}\,$, and from there $\,r=2\,$ and $\,\varphi = \frac{1}{4}(\pi + 2k\pi)\,$, which gives the $4$ roots for $k=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: Is the reason $k =0,1,2,3$ that, after that you get repeated roots ? @dxiv

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Yes, because $\,\frac{\pi + 2k\pi}{4} \equiv \frac{\pi + 2(k+4)\pi}{4}\pmod{2\pi}\,$.